# Can Blessing of Fervor be applied to a 1st/2nd level spell which has been heightened?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, metamagic

I have a specific scenario which I need clarification on. I want to cast a spell like sanctuary which can benefit from being in a higher spell slot with heighten spell and also from extend spell. **Not using any rods.**

So doing this with just the metamagic feats turns the spell into spell level (+1) + extend spell (+2) and heighten spell (+1). The spell is now a 4th level spell and lasts 2 rounds / CL.

But lets say I wanted to make this into a 2nd or 3rd level spell using heighten spell but the effect from Blessing of Fervor.

- Spontaneous Caster: Am I allowed to apply the extended effect from Fervor and then heighten the spell without removing the extended effect?
- Prepared Caster: Despite the spell having already been heightened, is the effect from Fervor allowed on the spell?

[Blessing of Fervor](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/b/blessing-of-fervor)

> Cast a single spell of 2nd level or lower as if it were an enlarged, extended, silent, or still spell.

Answer (score 6):

No to both questions.

A spontaneous caster still has to apply **all** *Metamagic* before casting a spell and Blessing of Fervor takes place once you cast so the level of the spell that you are casting must be 2nd or lower after applying all *Metamagic*.

For a prepared caster the answer is even simpler. If the spell takes up a higher spell slot than 2nd level it cannot use *Blessing of Fervor*.

Answer (score -3):

No, you can't, for many reasons:

- the reasons GreedyRadish explained.
- because you are trying to apply metamagic to a spell-like. Only real spells can benefit from metamagic, not spell-likes.

Comment: Which exactly is the spell-like ability?

Comment: In the question: "I want to cast a **spell like** sanctuary(...)"

Comment: I believe there is a comma missing there.

Comment: Hum, you can be right. Anyway the answer to the question is still a big "No".